# Set Text at center of layout that contains Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a situation like below

[image]

In my linear layout i added one View (MyView) that contains canvas

```
drawLayout.addView(new MyView(this,"a"));
```

Now i want to draw one text in canvas at **middle of the linearlayout**, for that i calculate linearlayout's height and width (drawWidth,drawHeight) and then wrote this,

```
canvas.drawText(letterTOdraw,drawWidth/2,drawHeight/2,mpaint);
```

But it was not draw correctly (not in center). After that i modify it as below

```
canvas.drawText(letterTOdraw,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,mpaint);
```

But nothing changed. When i calculate canvas height and width, i am surprised that i gave me 600 X 1024 , how it is possible that i set MyView into linearLayout that is only 951X359.

Thus i can't able to draw text at center of linearLayout.

I am stuck in this problem for last 5 hrs . help me to get out of this.

Comment: if you show ondraw method of your canvas.maybe we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your centering code is wrong. Your code will draw the text not in the center, but rather slightly to the bottom and to the right - the center of the canvas will be the top-left point of the text.

If you want to draw the text in the center, you need to take into account the size of the text - at `((canvas.getWidth() - letterWidth) /2, (canvas.getHeight() - letterHeight) / 2))`

Comment: Hello,still it not showing at center, i want to draw at center of linearLayout not in main canvas.

Comment: Why don't you just put a TextView in the middle of the linear layout, then? Or another Canvas and draw on it?